# How to get notification if Boolean variable has been changed?

Tags: plc

In PLC statement programming language usually I used F_TRIG or R_TRIG to get notification if Boolean variable has been changed from false to true or vice verse, but what about in case I want to get notification if the variable has been changed (for false/true to true/false)?

Comment: Which PLC?  Are you asking about a way to detect a change in a non-boolean value (WORD,BCD,Float,etc?)

Comment: Answer to this question depends entirely on what plc programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear from your question what it is your asking but is you want to check for change in multiple bools then put the checks in parallel to each other. If you want to check for change in a multibit variable, int for instance, you can use a storage variable to check against. The code in the PLC will depend on which brand you use but stl should look like this, assuming variables X and X_Stored are declared.

```
if X<>X_Stored
{
   X_Stored:=X;
   ...
};
```

Replace ... with whatever code you need.

Stating which PLC you use would make this question a lot easier to answer.